A VHS of kids going out to a picnic and zoo with Nursery Rhymes
I used to watch this movie on VHS when I was a child in the late 90s. Let me know if someone remembers this. 
It is NOT animated - real actors. 
So, it begins when kids of different ages get up in a dormitory (kind of a hostel, maybe). And the whole day is conveyed through many nursery rhymes. The day starts by them getting ready to go to a picnic of sorts, where they of course meet a lot of stuffed animals. 
And they go to have lunch in some place, travel in a red bus ('Wheels of the Bus go round and round' playing), go to the zoo (with 'Old McDonald had a farm' in the background) and then return back (with the rhyme 'Baa baa Black Sheep' playing in the background). 
It would be about an hour long or more, don't remember that well.

Sounds like A Day Full of Songs, a nursery rhymes VHS from 1993; it all unfolds as you described. Kids wake up at a dormitory then go on a day of fun, where they ride on a red double-decker bus (while singing The Wheels On The Bus), visit the zoo (while singing Old Macdonald Had A Farm) and have a picnic with Paddington Bear (Teddy Bears' Picnic). You can see the whole thing here; here's another song fron their visit to the zoo:



